# Unable to get image from whats app notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, whatsapp, notification-listener

I am working on the application which reads the data from notification using Notification Listener Service class. I have completed the text part but I am unable to store the image received in the notification.

I want to store images received in the WhatsApp application from the notification. I have tried all most all solutions of Stack Overflow but didn't get any solution. I have tried `Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE` but it always returns null.

I have seen many applications doing this but looks like I am missing something.

So if anyone could help in any way, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON`. 
On API 23+ there is `notification.getLargeIcon()` method to get the icon.

Comment: It gives sender's image not the actual image.